# Keil bit-fields allocates wrong size of union/struct

Tags: sizeof, unions, bit-fields, keil

```
typedef union {
 struct {
  union {
   struct {
    unsigned int dev_t : 4; // Device Type, see DEV_type_t
    unsigned int dev_n : 7; // Device Number
   };
   unsigned int id : 11; // CAN_ID
  };
  unsigned int online    : 1;
  unsigned int reserved  : 4;
 }; // 16 bit total
 uint16_t _raw;
} CAN_prefix_t;
```

After compilation `sizeof(CAN_prefix_t)` shows `3 bytes`, but expected to be `2 bytes` `(11+1+4 bits or 4+7+1+4 bits = 16 bits)`.

Could anyone advise how to define struct/union above in right way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (and for my project it's even better to have 2 "views" - from device and from CAN bus point of view):

```
#pragma pack(push,1)

typedef union {
    struct {
        unsigned int dev_n      : 7;
        unsigned int dev_t      : 4;
        unsigned int online   : 1;
        unsigned int reserved : 4;      
    } dev;
    struct {
        unsigned int id              : 11;
        unsigned int online    :  1;
        unsigned int reserved  :  4;
    } can;
    uint16_t raw;
} CAN_prefix_t;

#pragma pack(pop)
```

**IMPORTANT: Keil compiler allocates bit-fields in reverse order.**

And also Keil poorly works with nested unions.